How to find what relations exists between 2 nodes surrealdb?
In neo4j, we can achieve this through the following statement, but how to achieve it in surrealdb?
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE id(a) = node1_id AND id(b) = node2_id
RETURN EXISTS((a)-[r]-(b)) AS is_related

I cannot find a good example on Google or the official documentation to explain that case.

Assuming that I'm reading the Neo4J right (which I've never used before), I think this planned feature is what would be needed:
https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb/issues/3613
There are some related discussions inside there that include workarounds for the moment.
